# Show a instance where a may already be a string

Tags: haskell, show, typeclass

I'm working on a type that is a container which can contain essentially anything. Something like this:

```
data Foo a = Foo [a]
```

I'm working on a Show instance for this type.

```
instance (Show a) => Show (Foo a) where
       show (Foo x) = concat $ map show x
```

This works fine:

```
show (Foo [1,2,3]) -- creates the string "123"
show (Foo [True, False]) -- creates the string "TrueFalse"
```

However, sometimes the "a" contained within foo *is already a string* so the call "map show x" is unnecessary. The result of calling show on a string, is it places "" around it.

```
show (Foot ["A", "B"]) -- creates the string ""A""B""
-- what I'd like is the string "AB"
```

Is there a way to define a separate Show instance for (Foo String)?

Comment: This whole business smells rather fishy. The purpose of `Show` is to be a complement to `Read`, so that reading what you showed should be an identity function. Printing raw strings when showing data that contains strings is wrong anyway. Strings may contain all kinds of cruft that is not meant for human consumption as is and will mess your terminal hard. `show` not only adds quotes, but escapes the cruft.

Comment: I challenge the claim you make, "the call 'map show x' is unnecessary". Your proposed alternative output, `"AB"`, leaves ambiguities: besides your example input, both `Foo ["AB"]` and `Foo ["","A","","","B"]` would produce that same output.

Answer (score 6):

You can't do this sort of thing in standard Haskell. It can be done, but it's going to require a bit of compiler black magic. We're going to use some GHC extensions.

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}

data Foo a = Foo [a]

instance (Show a) => Show (Foo a) where
    show (Foo x) = concat $ map show x

instance {-# OVERLAPS #-} Show (Foo String) where
    show (Foo x) = concat x
```

`FlexibleInstances` lets us break the usual instance rules and write `Show (Foo String)`, when normally we should only be able to write `Show (Foo a)`. Then we annotate the former with `{-# OVERLAPS #-}` to suppress the compiler error that occurs when we have multiple overlapping instances for `Show (Foo a)`. The compiler is smart enough to choose the more specific instance, so a `Foo String` will always call the second instance, whereas a `Foo a` for any other `a` will call the first.

Example usage:

```
*Main> Foo [1, 2, 3]
123
*Main> Foo [True, False]
TrueFalse
*Main> Foo ["A", "B"]
AB
```

Is this good style? Probably not. I recommend rethinking your strategy and just providing a different function (say, `showFooString`) for the string case, as writing code like we've just done above is likely to confuse users. But if you really think this is the best way to do what you want to do, then go for it. Just bear in mind that your code is only really going to compile with GHC.